# Trying to make a corny comeback in latin, also happen to be clueless in latin

Tags: translation-check

One of my friends always has this status that goes "Per aspera ad abyssum" a variant of "Per aspera ad astra", though noticably more cynical and pessimistic.

I thought of "Through difficulties to hell, and through hell to heavens" to put a positive spin on it, but I am not sure if my latin attempt is correct, which is as it follows:

"Per aspera ad abyssum et per abyssos ad caelum"

Is this correct or will I make a fool out of myself?

Comment: Making a fool of oneself is a way-of-life, around here. It looks fine--an accusative-case festival!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Per aspera ad abyssum et per abyssos ad caelum"
>
> Is this correct or will I make a fool out of myself?

Yes, that's correct. You might also like

> Per aspera ad abyssum, ad astra per abyssum.

---

Since your sentence *is* Dante's journey, I leave this grand verse here:

> "E quindi uscimmo a riveder le stelle" (Inferno XXXIV, 139)

“and thence we came forth to see again the stars”.

[image]

--- Beautiful.